# Istio fails to route request to workload with different target port

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks, kubernetes-service

I have created a k8s service type load balancer listening on port 80 meanwhile the target port is set to 8080 which is the same port the container exposes. When I try to call the service with simple http get from the browser Istio doesn't route the request to workload container instead the request is reset after time out period.

I have also a virtual service that routes to the service on port 80 (the only port configured for the service). The same configuration works if the service port and container port are the same.

My kubernetes cluster is actually can AKS.
Is this a limitation in Istio or am I missing any configuration for Istio? I have also tried sidecars to receive request on 80/8080 and binding it to 127.0.0.1:8080 but with no luck.

Comment: Running istio on aks without problems. Can you please provide some config yml.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what's wrong here? If you use istio, then you'r service should be type ClusterIP instead of LoadBalancer, and you should use istio ingress gateway service with appropriate gateway and virtual service to manage the traffic flow from outside(the browser) and if you want to communicate inside the mesh you can use the clusterIP services ips/dns names. As @ChristophRaab already mentioned could you provide some yamls and what exactly would you like to achieve with them?

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to call the service with simple http get from the browser Istio doesn't route the request to workload container instead the request is reset after time out period.

If you use [istio](https://istio.io/), then your service should be type [ClusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) instead of [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types), and you should use istio ingress gateway service with appropriate [gateway](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/) and [virtual service](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/) to manage the traffic flow from outside(browser).

Traffic from outside -> istio ingress gateway -> gateway -> virtual service -> [envoy sidecar proxy -> pod]

If you want to communicate between pods inside the mesh then you can use the clusterIP services ip or dns names.

---

> I have also a virtual service that routes to the service on port 80 (the only port configured for the service). The same configuration works if the service port and container port are the same.

That's the correct way to do that.

I would suggest to start with [bookinfo application](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/) to understand how it works.

---

> My kubernetes cluster is actually can AKS. Is this a limitation in Istio or am I missing any configuration for Istio?

The only thing you have to add on AKS is to add the annotation to the istio-ingressgateway service.

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

You can use the [Istio Operator](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/operator/) to set that.

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  profile: default 
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          serviceAnnotations:
            service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```